# Oracle iPlanet webserver migration to WAS Liberty profile

Tags: migration, websphere-liberty, iplanet

I would like to know the steps involved in migrating the Oracle Iplanet webserver(v6) to WAS Liberty profile. Also please let me know the feasibility and the challenges involved.

Answer (score 0):

The changes needed will depend on the application being migrated. You can use the [binary scanner](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) tool to scan your application for changes needed to migrate to liberty. Run the tool against your war/ear/jar file(s) with the `--sourceAppServer=other --targetAppServer=liberty` options.

Comment: Also please let me know, how do I generate the Liberty configuration xml for J2EE resources configured in Oracle iPlanet6 server.

Comment: @user126401 iPlanet is ancient server, so unfortunately you will have to gather manually resources used by application from iPlanet (like Datasources, queues etc) and create them manually in the Liberty `server.xml`. You can find many examples of resource configuration in Liberty, but you can always ask if you will have problems.